# Update boolean in mongodb using nodejs REST API

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have an api to connect top the nodejs and on calling that api i want to update votes array to true such that everytime the api is called, new boolean should be added. How can i do this?

This is how my database is structured and i want to update votes on calling api:

```
{
    _id: "610415d6d20bdd34742b8294",
    createdAt: 1627657685015,
    description: " ",
    email: "hemankadariya29@gmail.com",
    phone: "123456789",
    tags: [
      "Food"
    ],
    votes: [
      true,
      true
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can update all data types but now i want to update boolean in an array of a particular Id

Comment: Got it, but what have you tried so far? Where is your code?!